# Problem understanding the use of differentials in equation for energy stored in a capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, voltage, capacitance, notation

I was going through the Feynman Lecures on Physics Vol. II and arrived at [section 8.1](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_08.html#Ch1-audio), where the equation for the energy stored in a capacitor is obtained.

> We consider now the energy required to charge a condenser. If the charge $Q$ has been taken from one of the conductors of a condenser and placed on the other, the potential difference between them is
> \begin{equation}
> V=\frac{Q}{C},
> \end{equation}
> where $C$ is the capacity of the condenser. How much work is done in charging the condenser? We imagine that the condenser has been charged by transferring charge from one plate to the other in small increments $dQ$. The work required to transfer the charge $dQ$ is
> \begin{equation*}
> dU=VdQ.
> \end{equation*}
> Taking $V$ from the first equation, we write
> \begin{equation*}
> dU=\frac{Q\,dQ}{C}.
> \end{equation*}
> Or integrating from zero charge to the final charge $Q$, we have
> \begin{equation}
> \label{Eq:II:8:9}
> U=\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{Q^2}{C}.
> \end{equation}

My confusion arises when $V=\dfrac{Q}{C}$ is replaced on the second equation. Why is it not $V=\dfrac{dQ}{C}$? Is $V$ a constant? and if so, $Q$ is also a constant, so it shouldn't matter if we wrote $dq$ instead of $dQ$, since it's just notation and has nothing to do with $Q$ and we would have the integral
\begin{equation*}
U=\int_0^QdU=\int_0^Q\dfrac{Q}{C}dq = \dfrac{Q^2}{C}
\end{equation*}
Maybe I'm getting confused by the notation. Are $U$ and $V$ functions of $Q$? Is this true $U'(q)=V(q)=\dfrac{q}{C}$?

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: $V$ and $U$ are functions of how much charge has moved.   Look at Feynman's third equation.  The change in potential energy is proportional to the charge that happens to be there ($Q$) when $\mathrm{d}Q$ is moved.  At first there is no charge, at the end the capacitor is fully charged.

Comment: The second equation does not come from the first.  It is a separate equation. The potential V is the potential energy per unit charge, so the second equation is just the energy U=Q V in differential form.

Answer (score 0):

*Why is it not $V=\frac {dQ}{C}?$*

$Q=CV\, \& \,Q+dQ =C(V+dV) \Rightarrow  dQ = C\,dV\Rightarrow dV = \frac {dQ}{C}$.

So the voltage is not constant when a charge $dQ$ is moved the voltage changes by $dV$.
So how to apply $V\,dQ$ or is it $(V+dV)dQ$ or $(V+\frac{dV}{2})dQ$ or . . . .
Well the answer is that it doesn't matter because you are dealing with infinitesimals and $(V+dV)dQ = V\, dQ + dV\,dQ \to VdQ$ as the second term is vanishingly small.